# Rails ERB iterate over array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to experiment with blocks and how to iterate over collections in ERB. I have a models in a one-to-many relatinship (Channel and their corresponding types).

## controller

```
class HomePageController < ActionController
   def index
    @channels =  Channel.all
   end
end
```

Then in the view, I iterate over all the attributes belonging to a Channel. When I want to print all types, this code gives me the desired output:

## view

```
<% @channels.each do |channel| %>
    <% @types.each do |type| %>
        <%= Type.find(type).name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

At first I tried to achieve this by using the `yield` keyword in a neat one-liner but I couldn't manage to print anything to the browser, only to the console

```
<% @types.each {|type| yield Type.find(type).name } %>
```

Is there an equivalent one-liner?

Comment: doesn't <%= @types.each {|type| Type.find(type).name } %> work?

Comment: is @types an array of integer ids?

Comment: `<%=` outputs the content, while `<%` just executes it. See answer by @srecnig.

Comment: @BradWerth yes an array of integer ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this method is so inefficient, you are doing n-queries, to find each record of type `Type` instead convert those into an array of types by using a single query in the controller, assume that that array is in `type_ids`

```
# controller
@channels = Channel.includes(:types) # avoiding n+1 queries

# view
<% @channels.each do |channel| %>
  # some channel info output
  <% channel.types.each do |type| %>
    <%= type.name %>
  <% end %> # types loop
<% end %> # channel loop
```

As @Almaron mentioned, you could render a partial for more simplification, if you have a partial called `_type.html.erb` you can call render directly

```
# view
<%= render channel.types %>
```

Rails will do all the iterating and rendering.

Comment: Actually the type_ids is a has_many relationship, for each parent type I can have an array of those type ids. So how would I do that in the controller?

Comment: `type_ids` is just a virtual name I made up,  i just used that because `@types` should be the types array, not the ids array, you can call it whatever you want, `ids` or anything

Comment: I meant: how should a nested type (one-to-many relationship) be taken care of in the context of passing data between the Controller and the View. E.g a Channel has many types. So to print all Channels and their corresponding types, should one actually create a datastructure in form of a map in the controller, and then access it in the view? Or should one create a helper function, passing the ids, and call it from the view? I don't have have problem with solving this, but I want to do it the Rails way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, could you add the controller code to the question too, that would help.

Comment: There's not much of a controller code atm. Only like 'def index \@channels = Channel.all end'. In the view, I iterate over @channels and print their attributes. Types is an attribute in a Channel, which is nested and a Channel can have many types.

Comment: check the updated answer, again that part of info about the controller actually makes a difference, it should be added to the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this kind of code does not belong to the view. Don't tackle the database from the view (in your case `Type.find()`). Move it to the controller where it belongs.

The second thing to note is the difference between `<%=` and `<%` tags. The first one outputs the returned result, while the second one doesn't. The problem with `.each` is that it returns the object it has been used on, so in your case if you just go `<%= @types.each {|type| Type.find(type).name } %>` you'll get the `@types` array printed out.

If you want to simplify that code, you can use a helper method for iterating and a partial for rendering each item. That way you get something like this
`<% collection_iterate @items, 'item_partial' %>`